# Logical container in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

We know Angular 2+ has something called as [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) which can be used to create a logical container and which does not gets rendered on DOM as the container itself creates a html comment.

At times in angularjs, we need to create an external template from an external file, which requires atleast one parent container else angularjs throws an error for no single parent.

If we need to mimic the same behavior like ng-container in angular js , so that its children gets rendered in dom, but the element itself gets rendered as html comment at runtime, How can we do that ?

Note: replace only puts its content, but to mimic exact behavior, it is required that element also gets created as html comment at runtime.

Comment: well that does not work. i created a directive with restrict as comment. it does not mark my element as comment.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).